# Error: Type '(key: String, value: Any)' has no subscript members with json

Tags: json, parsing, swift3

i'm new in swift 3 and i have this problem with json
this is my func, I don't know if is the correcta way to do

```
public static func parseResultsJSON(responseCars: [String : Any?]) -> Array<MisAutos>{
    var arrayMisAutos : [MisAutos] = [MisAutos]()

    if responseCars.count > 0{
        if let jArrayCars = responseCars[KeyWords.INFORMACION_G] as? [String : Any] {
            for jObjectCars in jArrayCars{

                let cars : MisAutos = MisAutos()

                cars.setAgAuto(agAuto: jObjectCars[KeyWords.AG_AUTO] as! String)

                cars.setMarca(marca: jObjectCars[KeyWords.MARCA] as! String)

                cars.setModelo(modelo: jObjectCars[KeyWords.MODELO] as! String)

                cars.setAgTipo(agTipo: jObjectCars[KeyWords.Ag_TIPO] as! String)

                cars.setNoSerie(noSerie: jObjectCars[KeyWords.NO_SERIE] as! String)

                cars.setUrlImage(urlImage: jObjectCars[KeyWords.ARRAY_IMAGES] as! [Int : String])

                cars.setPlacas(placas: jObjectCars[KeyWords.PLACAS] as! String)

                arrayMisAutos.append(cars);

            }
        }
    }
    return arrayMisAutos;
}
```

and this is my json

```
["Info": Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x618000054580>(
{
    id = 1;
    "type" = a;
    name = ACURA;
    Model = ILX;
    images =     (
    "werewr.werewr/images/image0.jpg",
    "werwer.werwer/images/image1.jpg",
    "werwer.werwer/images/image2.jpg",
    "werwer.werwer/images/image3.jpg"
    );
},
    {
        id = 2;
        "type" = b;
        name = BMW;
        Model = X6;
        images =     (
            "werewr.werewr/images/image0.jpg",
            "werwer.werwer/images/image1.jpg",
            "werwer.werwer/images/image2.jpg",
            "werwer.werwer/images/image3.jpg"
        );
}
    )
    ), "AutosPlan": Optional(3), "success": Optional(1)]
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the future please include the String keywords as they are present in the JSON and not non-english variable names referring to them, it makes your codes readability way worse and when debugging a JSON parsing error it is essential to see what keys you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input parameter is wrong. It should be an array of dictionaries, not just a dictionary.
Instead of this:

`public static func parseResultsJSON(responseCars: [String : Any]) -> Array<MisAutos>{`

You need this:

`public static func parseResultsJSON(responseCars: [[String : Any]]) -> Array<MisAutos>{`

The values also shouldn't be optional. You also shouldn't use force casting unless you are 100% your JSON response will always be correct.

Comment: Thanks! But now i have this problem with the modification "Cannot subscript a value of type '[[String: Any]]' with an index of type 'String'" at this line

if let jArrayCars = responseCars[KeyWords.INFORMACION_G] as? [String : Any]